# Сбитая кодировка при добавлении данных на русском в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Когда через форму заполняешь базу на русском, то в базу добавляются вопросительные знаки. Вот картинка формы -

[image]

Вот картинка результата добавления -

[image]

Подскажите, как это решить.

Comment: кодировка неверная указана либо в настройках базы, либо php. Используйте utf-8 и будет счастье.

Comment: Тогда пустые поля добавляет, а как кодировку в php прописать?

Answer (score 1):

После соединения с базой отправьте запросы

```
$db->query('set names utf8');
$db->query("set lc_time_names='ru_RU'");
```

Это поставит UTF-8 для текущего соединения с mysql и позволит получать на русском к примеру названия месяцев, дней недели и т.п.

Для браузера высылайте заголовки посредством header и устанавливайте тег meta. Плюс сам скрипт конечно же должен быть в UTF-8

---

после имеющиеся записи БД с неверной кодировкой вам проще удалить, т.к. они скорее всего будут возвращать неверный результат